# Failing to connect to Azure SQL database (PowerShell) via a service principal account

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-cli, azure-sql-server

I'm trying to establish a connection to an Azure SQL Database via a service principal (through a PowerShell script).

I believe I have followed the guidance issued by Microsoft but the connection cannot be established. My current configuration is:

- Azure SQL Server has an AAD administrator set up (AAD group)
- The AAD Group contains a service principal account (manually created)
- Azure SQL Server has a system managed identity (and has the Directory Reader role assigned to it)

It's my understanding that I do not need to explicitly execute `CREATE USER` for the service principal as it is already a member of the AAD Group which is an admin on the Azure SQL Server.

I've tried Azure CLI and AZ module commands, both to no avail.
As an example:

```
az login --service-principal -u "***" -p="***" --tenant "***"
$accessToken = az account get-access-token --resource https://database.windows.net --query accessToken
Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance "***.database.windows.net" -Database "***" -AccessToken $accessToken -Query "SELECT GETUTCDATE()"
```

The above generates an error on Invoke-Sqlcmd `Invoke-Sqlcmd: Login failed for user '<token-identified principal>'`

I've also tried sanitising the access token (as noticed it started/ended with `"`), and in doing so the error was broadly the same, however it did report the actual service principal (by ID)

`$accessToken = $accessToken -replace """", ""`

Produced the error `Invoke-Sqlcmd: Login failed for user '***@***'`

Answer (score 0):

**Issue was caused because of the role assignments "Reader role" to the service principal**

While establish a connection to an Azure SQL Database via a service principal two things we need to do

1. Add **contributor** role to Service Principal Id
2. Allow port 1433 from the sql server firewall with allowed network IP range.
   [image]
3. Upon role assignment tested with Azure Data Studio.  Able to connect with out any issues.
   NOTE: Make sure firewall rule need to allow along with 1433 port.

**Updates:**

4. Need to create a user with service principal name on database along with db_owner role

   create user  from EXTERNAL PROVIDER
   ALTER ROLE DB_OWNER ADD MEMBER servicePrincipalName>
5. Service Principal App Permissions needs to provide from Azure Active Directory to access via service principal account
   [image]

Please refer to Thomas Thornton article.

[Query Azure SQL Database using Service Principal with PowerShell – Thomas Thornton](https://thomasthornton.cloud/2020/10/06/query-azure-sql-database-using-service-principal-with-powershell/)